# code signing in java EAR

Tags: java, certificate, ear, signing, routines

We are trying to implement code signing routines for our project. The archive is EAR. When I research in google, we are seeing jar code signing certificates free or paid. Can anyone help whether we can do code signing for EAR, If yes, How?

Comment: You can sign an `EAR` just like you sign a `JAR`, e.g. using `jarsigner`.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: We are using Jboss server

Comment: Can someone suggest some code signing processes for EAR ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own keystore using keytool of jdk.
But this will be a self signed archive.

Else you can procure the signing certificate in your name from any CA such as Entrust, Verizon etc...

My question is why do you want to sign the EAR.

Comment: We need to sign the EAR to ensure that it is not tampered. I have very less idea here. Actually no idea. Jar signing is sufficient. We have jar files inside EAR

Comment: For integrity checking you can use JCE using BouncyCastle or OracleProvided